# Response times varying significantly in MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance

I have an asp mvc app hosted at www.jacquelinewhite.co.uk. When I use firebug (net tab or page speed) I'm seeing response times of 200 milliseconds for an action that isn't cached and about 30 for a cached action result. However, my reports from pingdom.com are showing an average of between 3 and 7 seconds for a response.

The application is set not to recycle and sits at a consistent memory level. I can't see any CPU spikes and basically everything looks fine, except the response times are a lot slower than I'd hope for.

I'm inclined to think it's not a problem with pingdom and the google webmaster tools shows the sites as slower than 54% of other sites.

Where else might I look at to identify the sites slowness?

Comment: The first thing I'd check is to make sure your assemblies are compiled for `RELEASE` and not `DEBUG`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as luck would have it, the Stackoverflow team has just released an [MVC Profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) (which was originally developed to profile this family of sites). The profiler is available from [code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) and also as a [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MiniProfiler). You should be able to use it to profile your site and perhaps spot any bottle-necks.

Another useful profiling-type tool is called [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/):

> "At its core Glimpse allows you to
>   debug your web site or web service
>   right in the browser. Glimpse allows
>   you to "Glimpse" into what's going on
>   in your web server. In other words
>   what Firebug is to debugging your
>   client side code, Glimpse is to
>   debugging your server within the
>   client."

Comment: Both these tools confirmed that my app was fine. I've tried a few other site monitoring tools and they all came with more sensible (and consistent) results. I'm starting to think pingdom is not very reliable.